# Visualization of descending count

Tags: python, graph, plotly, visualization, echarts

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    components       non_breaking_count breaking_count
0   paths-modified              22956   8640
1   endpoints-modified          22155   8149
2   endpoints-added              8109   5354
3   paths-added                  7375   4787
4   info-version                 5680   857
5   components-schemas-added     2555   1597
6   info-description             1940   762
7   tags-added                   1031   564
8   info-title                   859    551
9   servers-added                711    332
10  info-termsOfService          701    161
11  servers-deleted              609    262
12  components-schemas-deleted   588    938
13  components-securitySchemes   301    112
14  tags-modified                297    128
15  components-securitySchemes  229     171
16  components-parameters-added 209     239
17  tags-deleted                199     541
18  components-responses-added  183     164
19  info-contact-name           153     96
20  security-added              140     121
21  info-contact-email          132     110
22  servers-modified            120     32
23  info-license-name           115     46
24  info-license-url            105     36
25  paths-deleted                97     4979
26  info-contact-url             93     51
27  components-securitySchemes-deleted  87  71
28  endpoints-deleted            84     5612
```

I have been looking for a good way to visualize this with their counts and annotation( for all the components column). What i am looking for is one graph for breaking and another for non breaking.

I had a sliced bar chart in mind, with two bars for `breaking` and `non breaking`, however fitting in 28 values is a bit difficult, so I had to discard that option. I tried with nightingale chart in `echarts` as well, but the proportions are a mismatch somehow. Another way would be a `treemap`, but that and `pie chart` is something I wish to avoid.

Does anyone have any suggestions on which type of graph I could use to effectively visualize this data.

Comment: Plotly has a stacked funnel graph. See [this](https://plotly.com/python/funnel-charts/#stacked-funnel-plot-with-plotlyexpress) for reference.

Comment: I have seen into that, however it’s logically wrong and a bit misleading for my use case

Comment: would you consider breaking this apart into subplots with more than one row?

Comment: subplots as in? sorry I am a bit confused

Comment: subplot as in multiple plots on the same html page. for example, you could have [stacked plots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#stacked-subplots) and divide your 28 values into different bar charts on multiple rows

Comment: ahh I see, no I need it all together actually, to see the decline in size for all the metrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are several challenges here:

- amount of categories
- extreme value difference

Bar plots (either horizontal or polar) handle numerous categories well but it's not always easy to deal with the extreme value difference.  Additionally using a log axis with the bar plot could provide a useful visualization.  A downside to the log axis is it may not be fully comprehended with some audiences.

That said, I'd prefer to use a [Bubble Chart](https://plotly.com/python/bubble-charts) in this case so that I can use the marker size to [help illustrate the value's magnitude](https://plotly.com/python/bubble-charts/#scaling-the-size-of-bubble-charts).  A [log axis](https://plotly.com/python/log-plot/) can add further clarity.

For convenience I've put the data in a text file and imported via pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("visualization-of-descending-count.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
```

While the request specifies two seperate plots, a scatter could contain both sets of data and what I've gone with.  Further condideration can be given in how to scale the buuble size... either scaled to the max of both groups or the max for each group (see comments in example).

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
max_value = df[['breaking_count', 'non_breaking_count']].max().max()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name="Non-Breaking",
    x=df.non_breaking_count,
    y=df.components, 
    mode='markers', 
    marker=dict(
        size=df.non_breaking_count,
        sizemode='area',
        # unified scale between two groups using max_value
        sizeref=2.*max_value/(40.**2),
        # unique scale for each group
#         sizeref=2.*max(df.non_breaking_count)/(40.**2),
        sizemin=3)))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name="Breaking",
    x=df.breaking_count,
    y=df.components, 
    mode='markers', 
    marker=dict(
        size=df.breaking_count,
        sizemode='area',
         # unified scale between two groups using max_value
        sizeref=2.*max_value/(40.**2),
        # unique scale for each group
#         sizeref=2.*max(df.breaking_count)/(40.**2),
        sizemin=3)))

fig.update_layout(height=1000, width=1000,)
fig.show()
```

[image: base]

Switching to a log axis:

```py
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(type='log'))
fig.show()
```

[image: with log axis]

Side note, `components-securitySchemes` has two entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a [**bar of pie**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/bar_of_pie.html).

You can replace the age given in the example by the lower data in your set.